# Angular 2 SVG sprite

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

i have a sprite svg file. svg file include all icons

if i put this svg in my code it work

```
<svg:svg>
    <svg:use [attr.xlink:href]="'#loading-small'"></svg:use>
</svg:svg>
```

it working, but if i want to load it from path like

```
<svg:svg>
    <svg:use [attr.xlink:href]="'sprite.svg#loading-small'"></svg:use>
</svg:svg>
```

where i need to put the sprite svg? i get error

platform-browser.es5.js:2818 GET http://localhost:4200/sprite.svg

Comment: src/assets/ folder is where you store your global chunks